# assign `generated always as identity` values in Delta tables programmatically

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

Is there any way to programmatically access the mechanism used in Databricks to assign Delta table identity columns, so that you can assign the values to a Dataframe pre-insert?  Is this available in an `io.delta` class anywhere or is it something that happens internally in Databricks on insert?

Comment: Here's a Spark PR for this: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/38823

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy the PR shows how Spark would handle `generated always as ...` in general but I'm looking for the `identity` (ID generation) transformation specifically.